# mSigna: Signed, send, but 0 confs despite high fee (0.001 BTC)

Tags: confirmations, sending, msigna

Tried to send my first tx from mSigna today. Receiving was painless, but the send does not get included into a block since half a day, and dozens of blocks passed.

I unlocked the account, created the tx, signed and sent it. The confirmation count for my receiving tx still rises (as more blocks arrive), but the one for the sending tx stays 0. Sounds like enough support to me...

I feel I am missing important information, like I need to do some step in addition?

The only calculation for the fees I found is at [bitcoinfees](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), but it's based on average tx size. It currently recommends 0.0002712 BTC, which is well below the fee I payed.

[blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/8db88cce55a6ed213e847207a2c5cafa5cb5b487fa115825661b04400db8a6af) says "Transaction not found". Looking at the adress at blockchain.info, it says "0 transactions".

I'm running mSigna 0.10.6 with Bitcoin Core QT 0.14.2 (64bit) locally.

EDIT: As I read somewhere that transactions based on unconfirmed payments take longer than usual, I wanted to add that my receiving transaction is shown with over 6000 confirmations (again up from yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another wallet to test your network. Don't worry about the fee, it's enough. Mostly one tx will be confirm in 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks, jinsong. I am wondering what you mean be "test my network". Surely, the continuous arrival of confirmations for the receiveing tx (both at Bitcoin core and at mSigna) shows that my connection to the bitcoin nodes is good? Why would blocks come in, but no tx go out?

Comment: Maybe we can change the network setting to another Host and Port for a test? You can find a node [here](https://blockchain.info/ip-log), let's find out the problem together.

Comment: change the network setting of mSigna to another Host and Port, if you use Mac client, the setting options is in the Preferences Menu.

Comment: mSigna cannot connect to a few items on the list (I tried 10 items now). Error messages differ (German, so I'll translate): The target refused the connection; the target did not react properly; Network timed out; connection was terminated by local system. What I find suspicious is that the list stops with "last connected" 2017-08-24 17:44:34, which is roughly one month ago...

Comment: try 116.62.112.81 in Beijing of China and this 109.206.177.21 in EU, I've done a test with them on my own mSigna client and the state is connecting. My location is China, so you can try more different IPs.

Comment: If you use mSigna as well, maybe you know the meaning of the different patterns in the row background? The receiving transaction has a slightly dotted background, the sending transaction has a slightly darker background.

Comment: Also, I asked with the mSigna company about community or other forms of support, and they asked back whether I would be willing to organize a community...

Comment: Just tried the EU IP you sent. mSigna sync'ed the newest 50 blocks with this IP; the old receiving tx got a few more confirmations, but the new sending tx still is at 0 confirmations. Clicking "Transaction Signatures" (which is as far as I can get to a display of details, I think) shows a hash, the statement "Transaction is signed", and one row listing my keychain (with a closed lock symbol).

Comment: A few blocks have now arrived over the Bejing IP you sent. Same results as before, still 0 confirmations. I tried the "Resend Transaction" function, which only shows a dialog "Transaction has already been sent".

Comment: When the transaction has already been sent, just wait the miners to include your tx in a block for one confirmation. At the same time, you can check your tx on blockchain.info to check whether this tx has been broadcasted to the bitcoin network successfully.Now you can do another test, change your host and port to localhost, and send some bitcoin, then close the client and resent again to get the alert information. And then compare the new alert information to the one which is 'Transaction has already been sent' to see that whether there have some different and let me know.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the local chain data has not sync completely. When the full node has not sync data completely, it will not broadcast any tx before that because it can't check whether the tx meets all the tx rules. Check it, good luck.

Comment: Jinsong, nothing has changed regarding the state of my tx: It is still not listed at blockchain.info ("Transaction not found"). My local Bitcoin Qt has received the latest block as listed on blockchain.info, and mSigna also shows this block number twice in the status bar. Still, no confirmations. The dialog I get when I click "Resend transaction" is the same regardless of the node I connect to - "Error: Transaction already sent".

Comment: By the tests we have done, we knew that the problem is caused by broadcast step and sometimes the tx could be broadcasted successful and whether tx has been send or not that is not beyond on tx had been broadcasted to the bitcoin network or no when using mSigna. So I suggest three other kinds of test:1.Change your wallet to another. 2.  Change your Internet connection, maybe use mobile Hotspot for a little while to test. 3. When using mSigna, after create a tx, change the ip and port to see if it will be broadcasted successfully like the one you have done about EU IP.

Comment: The purpose of doing so is to check why the tx can't be broadcasted to the network, maybe the Internet nor the mSigna client. I knew you use Bitcoin QT, so you can create a tx test by this client too.